# Japanese / CJK font settings for proper horizontal alignment

Tags: fonts

I've had this right at one point in the past on one machine with a certain font type at a particular font size, but I can't seem to get it right again.

Look e.g. at how my org mode tables look once I add Japanese characters. Here are two examples using fonts that were supposed to align properly (I read somewhere).

[image: DejaVu Sans Mono Book 10]

[image: Insolata Medium 10]

Help!

This is version

> GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.14.5) of 2014-12-10 on gaia, modified by Debian

**Edit** A copy-and-pasteable version of a bunch of alignment problems for anyone who wants to try themselves:

```
| a 漢字       |   |
| b はどう     |   |
| f デショウ a |   |
| ﾊｰﾌ          |   |
| ｗｈｏｌｅ   |   |
| half         |   |
| ○            |   |
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a solution that may be the best one currently (I use this solution):

http://coldnew.github.io/blog/2013/11/16_d2f3a.html

Though the article is in Chinese, but you still can read the Emacs Lisp code easily to understand what mechanism it has done.

[My configuration example](https://github.com/kuanyui/.emacs.d/blob/master/rc/rc-basic.el#L102) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, kuanyui. I haven't tried it yet, because I meanwhile figured out a simple (partial) solution. Is your `emacs-font-size-pair-list` perhaps addressing the font size issue that I describe in my answer?

Comment: I cannot sure. But the size-pair-list is based on try-and-error for the fonts you're using (may be need some adjusts by yourself). So each zoom scale would be suitable if you set properly.

Answer (score 1):

The solution turned out to be surprisingly easy. After [adding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3958530/709537)

```
(set-default-font "Inconsolata-12")
```

to the end of my `~/.emacs`, it kind of (see below for details) worked.

[image: Emacs Inconsolata 12]

---

The Full story:

After copy-and-pasting the table into LibreOffice I noticed that Inconsolata worked, whereas DejaVu Sans Mono does not - which depends, I suppose, on my xorg font substitution settings. (My LibreOffice font substitution settings are empty.) To wit:

[image: LibreOffice rendering of org-table format]

That lead me to just play around with Inconsolata in emacs a little more, and to the `set-default-font` solution mentioned above.

Not all font sizes work however, and if I increase/decrease the font size, the alignment gets messed up again. Here are the results for the sizes I tried:

```
━━━━━━━━━━━
 size  ok? 
───────────
    6  ok  
    8      
   10      
   12  ok  
   14      
   16      
   18  ok  
   20      
   22  ok  
   24      
   26      
━━━━━━━━━━━
```

There is also one minor issue which I guess must be blamed on org-table, that is when I use the `TAB` key to navigate through cells, the formatting sometimes changes for the worse. The following is the result of pressing `TAB` in the leftmost cell:

[image: TAB in org-table]

Luckily though, a quick `C-c C-c` will repair the whole table again.

**Edit** Turns out there are still some characters that do not align properly. Neither in LibreOffice, nor in emacs. Example:

```
character: ○ (displayed as ○) (codepoint 9675, #o22713, #x25cb)
```

Corresponding screenshot:

[image: some characters still don't align]